# One method referenced and the other not from same driver in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have this strange error. I am using `MongoDB.Driver version 2.17` and this code is okay:

```
return GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey).FindAll();
```

But this one throws error:

```
return GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey).FindAll().AsQueryable();
```

The error it returns is the following:

`MongoCollection` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
As I saw it is from `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy` which is added in references.

Comment: Yes, I tried something like: IMongoCollectionExtensions.AsQueryable<T>(GetCollection(GetCollectionName(collectionName), federatedDBKey));
But then the error is: cannot convert from MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection to MongoDB.Driver.IMongoCollection

Comment: do not use legacy driver (deprecated long time ago) and use modern instead

Comment: @dododo But in official documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabase_GetCollection.htm on assembly it writes this driver. Which one is modern?

Comment: it just says that this class presents. See Mongo Collection here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/connecting/

Comment: I would also recommend unreference this nuget: `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy`

Comment: Thank you for advice. I tried that, but now it says: MongoCollection is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Comment: The only one I am referencing are MongoDB.Driver and MongoDB.Bson (both 2.17)

Comment: @dododo I tried your advice one more time and it is okay, everything goes through, but the new problem is created as then IMongoQuery is not recognized, but when I add back MongoDB.Driver.Legacy.dll driver it is recognized but the error from post is raised

Comment: IMongoQuery is a legacy api. Read the above documentation

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/definitions/

Comment: @dododo Thank you. Yes, I know, but I wanted to add that legacy so the changes that I have to make are minimal, but it looks like there is no shortcut, I have to remove it and update without it, and change a lot of code. Thank you for your time and help